# NUXT Using shared styles and scripts outside of project location

Tags: typescript, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm planning to share code between 2 NUXT projects, namely the CMS UI and the public facing UI. My files look something like this:

```
repo
|- shared
|  |- sass
|  |  `- main.sass
|  `- ts
|     `- test.ts
|- public (NUXT project)
|  |- ...
|  |- nuxt.config.js
|  `- tsconfig.json
`- cms (NUXT project)
```

I've set webpack alias and css in `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```
css: ['Shared/sass/main.sass'],
build: {
  extend(config, ctx) {
    config.resolve = config.resolve || {}
    config.resolve.alias = config.resolve.alias || {}
    config.resolve.alias.Shared = path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared')
  }
}
```

as well as typescript path in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
  "~/*": [
    "./*"
  ],
  "@/*": [
    "./*"
  ],
  "Shared/*": [
     "../shared/*"
  ]
},
```

However, when I actually try running `nuxt` or `import {test} from 'Shared/ts/test'`, they can't seem to resolve the paths.

CSS failure:

```
 ERROR  Could not compile template xxx\\repo\\public\\node_modules\\@nuxt\\vue-app\\template\\App.js: Cannot resolve "Shared/sass/main.sass" from "xxx\repo\public\Shared\sass\main.sass"
```

Typescript failure:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                       friendly-errors 22:16:27

error                                                                                                                                         friendly-errors 22:16:27
                                                                                                                                   friendly-errors 22:16:27
      TS18002: The 'files' list in config file 'tsconfig.json' is empty.
                                                                                                                                              friendly-errors 22:16:27
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 42:0-37 50:7-11
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

Please note that when trying to import `.ts` inside the nuxt project, there isn't this error.

**Does anyone know how to share code between nuxt projects under a unified repository?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my solution was to use Lerna for management. It created symlinks inside `node_modules` for management, but this alone isn't solving problem with importing in JS and TS.

**For JS, a webpack alias must be set to the location in `node_modules`. Resolving for symlinks must also be turned off for webpack, otherwise there will be problems in TS.**

A general note is `import xxx from '@ui/shared/xxx'` failed for me on client-side route change but not browser URL change, `import xxx from 'Shared/xxx'` must be used. *I don't know why, so if you know, please write a comment.*

<sub>**nuxt.config.ts**</sub>

```js
  // ...
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    extend (config, ctx) {
      config.resolve = config.resolve || {}
      config.resolve.symlinks = false
      config.resolve.alias = config.resolve.alias || {}
      config.resolve.alias.Shared = '@ui/shared'
    }
  }
  // ...
```